# Simple error with string variables

Tags: c++, string

Ok so I am a beginner to C++, using Visual Express C++ 2010 as my compiler. I have an assignment to create a program that calculates the net pay and budget of John Smith. I should be able to use the string variable 'John Smith', I used #include . I'm not sure why it says that I exceed the character count, because I should be using a string, not a variable. Sorry for the excessive comments, they're required for the assignment. And I'm sure that this is a very basic code format, but as I said, I'm new. Thanks in advance

```css
// Module 2 Programming Challenge Right.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"



// This program should calculate the base pay and budget of John Smith
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int BasePay;  // I am Ben Chilton, this is the Module 2 programming challenge, this was started on 1/26/2015
 int Commission;  // The purpose of this program is to calculate the gross pay, deductions, net pay, and sales value
 int GrossPay;   // of the employee John Smith. It also calculates his budget by using his net pay
 int Deductions;
 int NetPay;
 int Sales;
 int HousingBudget; 
 int FACBudget; // Food and clothes budget
 int EntBudget; // Entertainment budget
 int MiscBudget; // Miscellaneous budget
 string JohnSmith; //string should have a use? It's not highlighted blue, even though I used " #include <string> "
       // I'm using a string variable here, not character, not sure what the problem is
 BasePay = 900;
 Sales = 3500;
 Commission = (Sales * 6) / 100; // He earns 6% commission on sales, hence multiplying by 6 and dividing by 100
 GrossPay = Commission + BasePay; // Gross pay is his base pay plus his commission on sales
 Deductions = (GrossPay * 18) / 100; // Again I used multiplication and division to calculate percentages
 NetPay = GrossPay - Deductions; // His net pay is his gross pay minus his deductions, done here
 HousingBudget = (NetPay * 30) / 100; // 
 FACBudget = (NetPay * 15) / 100;
 EntBudget = (NetPay * 50) / 100; // Interesting budget choices haha
 MiscBudget = (NetPay * 5) / 100;

 JohnSmith = 'John Smith';  // Not sure why it is identifying this as a character, not a string

 cout << "Hello " << JohnSmith << " . We'll be calculating your income and budget. \n";
 cout << "Your base pay is " << BasePay << " dollars. \n";
 cout << "You made " << Sales << " dollars in sales. \n";
 cout << "You earned " << Commission << " dollars in commission from your sales. \n";
 cout << "Your gross pay is " << GrossPay << " dollars . \n";
 cout << "Your deductions are " << Deductions << " dollars. \n";
 cout << "Your net pay is " << NetPay << " dollars. \n";
 cout << "Your housing budget is " << HousingBudget << " dollars. \n";
 cout << "You have " << FACBudget << " to spend on food and clothes. \n";
 cout << "Your budget for entertainment is " << EntBudget << " dollars. \n";
 cout << "That leaves you with " << MiscBudget << " dollars to spend on anything else. \n";

}
```

Comment: `JohnSmith = "John Smith";` Double quotes, not apostrophes. Curiously, you know enough to write `"Hello "` and not `'Hello '`.

Comment: Oh wow haha, that was careless of me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using wrong syntax for assigning the string. A string is assigned like **string var= "John Smith"** . The syntax you are using is for assigning the character. Like if you want to assign a char to a var then it would be like **char ch = 'A'**.
     I hope it would help.

Answer (score 2):

In C everything you embrace in single quotes (`'c'`) is treated as a character. If you want to make a string use double quotes: `"John Smith"`.

Comment: Thank you haha, this was not explained in my textbook for some reason

Answer (score 2):

The compiler thinks that `'John Smith'` should be a character because you are using single quotes instead of double quotes. In c++, `'x'` means a `char`, whereas `"x"` means a `const char[2]`, that is a string literal. To use strings, use `"John Smith"`.